# jquery accordion: open specified panel on close other panel

Tags: jquery, panel, accordion

I am totally new to JQuery and javascript and could really use some help.

I want put together an accordion that has 8 panels and the default panel is #8. It is open when the page loads. By default, the #8 will close when I open any other panel, and stays closed unless I specifically open it, regardless of which other panel I open or close.

What I need to know is this: Is it possible to automatically open #8 each time I close an open panel.

For example, I open panel 3, which closes all currently open panels. When I close panel 3, I want panel 8 to open automatically.

Is that possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. Here's an example using jQuery UI:

```
$(function() {
    var activePanel = 2; //Set to the zero-based index of the panel you want to open
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        active: activePanel,
        activate: function(event,ui){
            //If a panel other than our default is collapsed
            if(!ui.newPanel.length && $(this).find('.ui-accordion-content').index(ui.oldPanel) != activePanel){
                $(this).accordion('option','active',activePanel);
            }
        }
    });
  });
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/7nb9T/)**

Comment: This does work, however it doesn't look great.  Normally if you select a panel other than the one that's open, it starts to expand at the same time the other one contracts.  Using your code, it does not start to expand the new panel until after the other one has already closed.

I'm not sure if there's any way around this.

Comment: @matthew_360 I don't know why you're seeing that but in the demo fiddle I see both panels animating at the same time

Comment: It works the way I describe in your fiddle as well.  At least for me in Chrome, Firefox and IE.  I click "Section 1" and that section opens.  Then I click "Section 1" again, that section closes, and then when it has finished contracting, "Section 3" then expands.

I had a couple other developers in my office test it as well and they all got the same thing.

Comment: @matthew_360 Ahh I see what you mean now. Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/7nb9T/14/) that now opens the default panel at the same time another panel is closed.